# How to check if data follows a specific distribution?

Tags: statistical-significance, model-evaluation

I have got xgboost model trained on binary classification problem. 
Scores are in continuous range from 0 to 1.
How can I check if those scores comes from given distribution (e.g beta). Does it make sense, are there any constraints?